# What is the ideal steps in using predicted segmentation masks for watershed post processing?

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, watershed

I am experimenting with object segmentation(round shaped objects that are often occur close together). I have used UNET deep neural network architecture for segmentation and obtained segmentation masks. I saved those in npy format.
I am a beginner in this area. I would like to know the ideal steps that I should follow now, if I want to apply watershed on the predicted masks with the aim of separating the objects.
I guess I need to convert the binary mask predicted to  some form so that I can obtain some kind of markers indicating centroids.

Please help

Comment: If you want separate masks for each object in the a particular category you should take a look at instance segmentation instead of semantic segmentation.

Comment: Yes I have read about instance segmentation using mask rcnn, but I was wondering whether we can separate the objects using a simple watershed in combination with unet.